# sending key presses to minimized window

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to send key press to window by it's hwnd.

`PostMessageA(FindWindow(NULL, WindowName);, WM_KEYDOWN, 0x0D, 0)`

If window is not minimized - it's works perfectly. But if windows is minimized - window ingores that.

I'm also tried SendMessage, but SendMessage not works in any state.

Please, help

Comment: "*it works perfectly*" - [no, it doesn't](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: Even if posting a message was correct, you are only posting the key down message, you forgot the up message.

Comment: What's kind of your target window? And how do you determine it works or ignored?

Comment: Why would a minimised window process those messages? It's minimised. It can't have input focus. It would be worth read some of the multitude of articles explaining that you can't fake input in this manner.